# Searching Excel column for single word

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file that has a column with names. I am trying to write a macro so that when I search the column I obtain every record that has that name. The problem I am having is that in a single cell there may be 1, 2 or even more names (i.e. I'm searching for "DAVE", but in a single cell there may be "DAVE" "ANDY" "FRANK"). Currently my code is picking up all the records that have ONLY "DAVE", but if a cell has "DAVE" and any other names it does not pick it up. Is there a way to code my macro such that it will pick up these that I'm missing?

Currently this is my if statement:

```
If WsG.Cells(G_Row, 2).Value = "DAVE" Then
   WsG.Rows(G_Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Ws2.Rows(S2_Row)
   S2_Row = S2_Row + 1
End If
```

So I'm looking in WsG, column 2 for "DAVE". Then, trying to copy the row over to a new worksheet.

Comment: It is hard to find the problems in you code without the actual code. Please [edit] your question and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Like` command:

```
WsG.Cells(G_Row, 2).Value Like "*DAVE*"
```

Comment: Scott, this worked like a charm. Thanks for the guidance and quick help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, use the [InStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function):

```
If InStr(1, WsG.Cells(G_Row, 2).Value, "DAVE", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```